# jQuery - List item change div class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, replace

Something is wrong with my code, as it is not currently working!
The problems are is that it doesn't do what I want it to. That is change the image when the link in the `<li>` list is clicked.
The class of the image wrapper div tag wants to change when the link is clicked to the class defined in the link.
I have the following:

```
<div class="span3">
                <h4 style="line-height: 0px; text-decoration: ; color: #060; display:inline;"><i class="icon-angle-right" style="display:inline;"> Our Offices</i></h4>
                <li><a href="#mg-london">
                <address>
                    <strong>Head Office - London</strong><br />
                    Suite 304, Crown House<br />
                    North Circular Road<br />
                    London NW10 7PN<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 020 8961 2632<br>
                </address>
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="#mg-sheffield">
                <address>
                    <strong>Northern Office</strong><br />
                    133 Abbeydale Road<br />
                    Sheffield<br />
                    S7 1FE<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 0114 438 8047<br>
                </address>
                </a></li>
            </div><!-- span3 -->


            <div class="span3">
                <h4 style="line-height: 0px; text-decoration: ; color: #060; display:inline;"><i class="icon-angle-right" style="display:inline;"> Our Stores</i></h4>
                <li><a href="#mg-dewsbury">
                <address>
                    <strong>Dewsbury</strong><br />
                    102 Pionier House<br />
                    Halifax Road<br />
                    WF13 4JJ<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 0192 445 9740<br>
                    <abbr title="Email">@:</abbr> Dewsbury@familiesrelief.org.uk
                </address>
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="#mg-birmingham">
                <address>
                    <strong>Birmingham</strong><br />
                    517 Moseley Road<br />
                    Birmingham<br />
                    B12 9BX<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 0121 440 8840<br>
                    <abbr title="Email">@:</abbr> Birmingham@familiesrelief.org.uk
                </address>
                </a></li>
            </div><!-- span3 -->

            <div class="span3" style="margin-top: 22px;">
                <li><a href="#mg-ealing">
                <address>
                    <strong>Ealing</strong><br />
                    93 The Broadway<br />
                    West Ealing<br />
                    W13 9BP<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 0208 567 3399<br>
                    <abbr title="Email">@:</abbr> Ealing@familiesrelief.org.uk
                </address>
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="#mg-halifax">
                <address>
                    <strong>Halifax</strong><br />
                    Diversity Project<br />
                    198 Queens Road<br />
                    HX1 4NE<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 0142 232 2550<br>
                    <abbr title="Email">@:</abbr> Halifax@familiesrelief.org.uk
                </address>
                </a></li>

            </div>

            <div class="span3" style="margin-top: 22px;">
                <li><a href="#mg-greenford">
                <address>
                    <strong>Greenford</strong><br />
                    64 The Broadway<br />
                    Ruislip Road<br />
                    Greenford UB6 9QJ<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 0208 578 9080<br>
                    <abbr title="Email">@:</abbr> Greenford@familiesrelief.org.uk
                </address>
                </a></li>

                <li><a href="#mg-sheffield">
                <address>
                    <strong>Sheffield</strong><br />
                    Al Shifa Charity Shop<br />
                    133 Abbeydale Road<br />
                    Sheffield S7 1FE<br />
                    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> 0114 438 8047<br>
                    <abbr title="Email">@:</abbr> Sheffield@familiesrelief.org.uk
                </address>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

The script:

```
$('ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cl = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $('.map-wrapper').removeClass().addClass('map-wrapper '+cl);
});
```

The css of two of the classes:

```
.mg-sheffield {
    background-image: url(../img/map/sheffield.png);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src=//ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/local/map_gradient.png, sizingMethod=scale)";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/sheffield.png);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/sheffield.png);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/sheffield.png);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/sheffield.png);
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/sheffield.png);
    background-position: center;
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 1600px;
}

.mg-dewsbury {
    background-image: url(../img/map/dewsbury.png);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src=//ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/local/map_gradient.png, sizingMethod=scale)";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/dewsbury.png);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/dewsbury.png);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/dewsbury.png);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/dewsbury.png);
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.294) 77%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.497) 91%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(../img/map/dewsbury.png);
    background-position: center;
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 1600px;
}
```

and the image wrapper:

```
<div class="map-wrapper mg-sheffield"></div>
```

So, this has a few problems. First of all, the class doesn't change when the address is clicked. Secondly, this actually removes the use of ALL of the links on my page other than the ones in the list. This means the navbar etc.

Any help, greatly appreciated! I can't figure it out..

Comment: I don't see any `<ul>` tags in what you posted. There's a `</ul>`, but inside it there's a whole lot of invalid markup.  You can't nest a `<div>` directly inside a `<ul>` - the only direct children of a `<ul>` element should be `<li>` elements.

Comment: You should def fix your html and edit your question with it.